# Accuracy metrics for Azure cognitive search

Tags: azure, query-optimization, azure-cognitive-search, precision-recall

We are planning to use the semantic search feature for processing a natural language query and surface relevant results

Given that precision and recall are standard metrics for measuring ML/search related problemms, how do we get to learning about precision and recall for Azure cognitive search.

Tried looking on MS documentation for COgnitive search but could not find relevant results(pun unintended)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the delay on this.

You may leverage this approach, use the built-in diagnostic logs in Azure Cognitive Search to measure precision and recall. The diagnostic logs provide detailed info about the search queries and results, including the number of documents returned, the relevance score of each document, and the query terms used. You can use this information to calculate precision and recall for your search queries.

To enable diagnostic logs in Azure Cognitive Search, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the Azure portal and navigate to your Azure Cognitive Search
   service.
2. Click on the "Diagnostic logs" tab in the left-hand menu.
3. Click on the "Add diagnostic setting" button.
4. Enter a name for the diagnostic setting and select the desired log
   categories.
5. Choose the destination for the logs (e.g., Azure Storage, Event Hub,
   etc.).
6. Click on the "Save" button to save the diagnostic setting.

Once you have enabled diagnostic logs, you may use a tool like Azure Log Analytics to analyze the logs and calculate precision and recall for your search queries.

You may also use the Azure Cognitive Search REST API to retrieve the search results and calculate precision and recall programmatically.

Reference:

[Enable diagnostic logging for Azure Cognitive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/diagnostic-logging)

[Monitoring Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/monitor-azure-cognitive-search)

Comment: I don't see a way how we can calculate precision and recall as per the documentation, Could you please share on what fields from the log analytics via AzureActivity or AzureDiagnostics?